# Armadillo Calls Internal Accelerate Libraries on iOS

Tags: ios, blas, armadillo, accelerate-framework

I recently tried to use Armadillo on iOS to do some matrix computing. The App worked on my development iPhone, but Apple gave me the error message when trying to publish it in the Appstore. It seems that Armadillo calls some BLAS functions which are internal. I searched the web with the message, but had not found anything useful. I also found calling BLAS functions with "cblas_" prefix, e.g. cblas_dgemv, directly from my code would not cause the error. However, that made the use of armadillo meaningless.

I wonder if anyone has encountered the same problem, and what the solution is. I’m suspecting it’s something related to some macro in config.hpp. Thank you very much for your kindly help.

Error message:

Non-public API usage:

•   The app references non-public symbols in ***: _sgemm_, _sgemv_, _ssyrk_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Accelerate BLAS implementation supports a bunch of redundant symbols to facilitate divergent function naming schemes of various fortran compilers. Strictly speaking these are intended to be used (by your fortran compiler) so you probably have some arguing ground that they are not private interfaces.  If the AppStore is still giving you trouble, file a bug against Apple and ask them to fix the bookkeeping on the interfaces so they can be used.

It would be simpler to just start using the cblas_ interfaces in the headers though.